# I have a sealed pkg of gorgonzola cheesw dated March 2018. It is June. Does it go bad?

Tags: cheese

Gorgonzola dated March 2018 vacuumed packed and never opened. It is June and blue. Is it good?

Comment: Isn't gorgonzola already as bad as it can get. Can anything compete with all that bacteria and mold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to eat moldy cheese if you slice off the edges?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/is-it-safe-to-eat-moldy-cheese-if-you-slice-off-the-edges)

Comment: @Bev was it blue when you bought it?

Answer (score 2):

The date on your package of cheese is most likely a "best by" date.  This means that the manufacturer assumes that the quality of the product begins to degrade by that time.  It DOES NOT mean that the product suddenly becomes unsafe to consume.  Whether or not it is "good" will be up to your taste buds, but I would assume it is safe to consume. Cheese has enough salt and (particularly blue cheese) "good/safe" bacteria, that nothing harmful would be growing in your sealed, properly refrigerated package of Gorgonzola.